# Android CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine onDraw draw a vector xml

Tags: android, canvas, watch, ondraw, android-vectordrawable

I have a VectorDrawable xml, when creating a watch face for android, in onDraw(Canvas canvas, Rect bounds) method, can I draw this vectorDrawable? Like canvas.draw(vector.xml), I am not sure how, please help!

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="64dp"
    android:width="64dp"
    android:viewportHeight="600"
    android:viewportWidth="600" >
    <group
        android:name="rotationGroup"
        android:pivotX="300.0"
        android:pivotY="300.0"
        android:rotation="45.0" >
        <path
            android:name="v"
            android:fillColor="#000000"
            android:pathData="M300,70 l 0,-70 70,70 0,0 -70,70z" />
    </group>
</vector>
```

Comment: yes,  you can draw it, see Drawable javadocs

Comment: Yeah I see it, and i think I must use mrVector to draw for now. Can you give good example?

Comment: Its just two lines of code...

Comment: Did you actually try it? I tried that and it doesn't work.

Comment: I didn't try mrVector but it will work like any other Drawable

Answer (score 2):

Here is simple code of WatchFaceService.Engine

```
private class Engine extends CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine {

    private Drawable mVectorDrawable;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        super.onCreate(holder);
        ...
        Resources resources = FooBarWatchFace.this.getResources();
        mVectorDrawable =resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.rounded);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas, Rect bounds) {
        int width = bounds.width();
        int height = bounds.height();
        ...
        mVectorDrawable.setBounds(0,0,width,height);
        mVectorDrawable.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```